# refresh a textbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want a macro that creates a textbox in Worksheet2 when I write something in Worksheet1!A1. The problem is that I want it to refresh whenever I refresh the data.
I made one but is runs the macro again, so I am left with several textbox, one on top of the others. Also I want to delete the textbox if the cell is empty.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
Sub criarcaixastexto()

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("Folha1!A1").value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Call criarcaixastexto
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of creating newtextboxes, you could have one TextBox created and then just change the value of that TextBox when cell A1 is changed.

Comment: @danieltakeshi - its a nice idea, but the OP wants to delete it when the value is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I just gave a tip, because i think that changing the TextBox value is simpler and has a better time performance.

Comment: @danieltakeshi - it is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore empty values change the event to this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'to avoid multiple selection.
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        RemoveShapes
        If Len(Target) > 1 then Criarcaixastexto
    End If
End Sub
```

This will remove the shapes, before writing new ones.

```
Sub RemoveShapes()

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then shp.Delete
    Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but when I delete the value in A1, the shape is not deleted. Is that possible? It does delete the old ones but if the cell is empty I still have the textbox

Comment: now I am trying to expand my code to more lines and I am getting a problem with the last macro again.

`Sub criarcaixastexto()

   Dim wsActive As Worksheet
   Dim box As Shape

For i = 1 To 3
   
   Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)
   
   Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 20, 100, 50)

   box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
   Next
   

End Sub`

so i changed this one and it works but now the one that starts the macro just by imputing nrs doesn't. Can you help me out?